# Set Global setting AIRPLANE_MODE_ON with device policy controller app (No rooted device)

Tags: android, settings

Is it possible to set Global settings like airplane mode programmatically via device policy controller app or in other ways, without a rooted device?

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`, and I set via adb my app as device policy manager.

When I try to set this global settings the system throws a `SecurityException permission denial`.

Comment: only system apps can use `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` permissions. To make your app a system app:1) using root move it to sytem apps directory. 2) make a custom firmware for certain device, and pre-install your app as system app in it. So basically there is no way

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I thought so, Thanks you for confirming.